# Intents and Entities defined in Microsoft Bot Composer do not stay in sync with LUIS Authoring service

Tags: botframework

The intents, entities, and example phrases I've defined in Bot Composer are not sync'ing with my LUIS Authoring resource.
Composer screen:
[Composer Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlEvP.png)

LUIS Authoring Screen after sync:
[LUIS Authoring Screen after sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIPl9.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running or publishing the bot? That's when it gets synced.

You could also try manually updating it with the [Bot Framework CLI](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-cli/blob/main/packages/luis/README.md#bf-luisbuild).

Comment: Yes - I tried to publish the lu file below:

Comment: Yes - I tried to publish again and the AccountBalance intent has 6 example phrases in the lu file in composer and the LUIS authoring resource only has 2 example phrases in the AccountBalance intent.

Comment: If you are still having an issue with this, verify that the knowledgebase Id and endpoint key (sometimes called the authoring key) are the same. If you pre-created the QnA knowledgebase, Composer (I think) will create a new knowledgebase with new Id and endpoint key. These will be saved in the appsettings.json file.